# OData Serialization

Tags: odata

I'm running into a oData Serialization error with an object with multiple levels.

The structure of my class is as follows

```
class Cons{
    public string Left {get; set;}
    public string Right {get; set;}
    public string Opr {get; set;}
}

class Rate {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<ICollection<Cons>> Rules {get; set;}
}

class Prd {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<ICollection<Cons>> Rules {get; set;}
    public ICollection<ICollection<Rate>> Rates {get; set;}
}
```

I run into the following serialization whenever `Cons` collection of the `Rate` class has some data:

```
"message":"ODataResourceSerializer cannot write an object of type 'Collection(Edm.Cons)'
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/complex-type-inheritance-in-odata-v4

Comment: http://odata.github.io/WebApi

Comment: https://www.odata.org/blog/trippin-new-odata-v4-sample-service

Comment: If you've solved this issue could you please write the solution?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO Hi, do you have any suggestions or hints about what this is about and how to solve it?

Comment: The problem is...the persons EMD Model doesn't tell OData "how" to build implementation of ICollection<T>.  While "simple" entity types are a minor entry in the EDM Configuration...complex types are much harder.  That is why I posted these links.  You will need to go through them & figure out HOW to manage COMPLEX TYPES.

That said...

Try concretizing the ICollection to something more specific like List<T>